# command runs in terminal but not via /bin/sh

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If I run this command it works fine in the terminal:

```
for dirname in $(ls -d dir/checkpoint/features.txt/20*);do;echo "hello";done
```

But when run through /bin/sh -c it gives an error

```
/bin/sh -c "for dirname in $(ls -d dir/checkpoint/features.txt/20*);do;echo "hello";done"
```

ERROR:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `dir/checkpoint/features.txt/201108000'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: `dir/checkpoint/features.txt/201108000'
```

My default shell is /bin/bash. I cant seem to understand what is causing this. My default implementation for running all shell commands in my program is by appending /bin/sh -c to them. It is the first time i am seeing this issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to escape characters like ", *...

Comment: Is `/bin/sh` the same as `/bin/bash`?  On (older versions of) Solaris, for instance, `/bin/sh` is not a POSIX shell and does not recognize `$(...)` notation.  Did you try enclosing the command in single quotes.

Comment: Since you've added another set of double quotes, sh is not parsing it the way you think it reads. Use single quotes on the outside instead.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This shows the difference between the two shells http://askubuntu.com/questions/141928/what-is-difference-between-bin-sh-and-bin-bash. I tried with single quotes too but it disnt work

Comment: @fedorqui Escaping didnt help either!

Comment: Try this:`/bin/sh -c "for dirname in $(ls -d dir/checkpoint/features.txt/20*);do;echo hello;done"`

Comment: @fedorqui sorry doesnt work. I tried removing all double quotes and * like this and still failed: `/bin/sh -c "for dirname in $(ls -d dir/features.txt/201107000);do;echo hello;done"`

Comment: `ls` should never be used in scripts. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Also, you need to use single quotes on the outside, not double quotes. `/bin/sh -c 'for dirname in dir/checkpoint/features.txt/20*; do echo "hello"; done'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to parse the output of `ls`, especially with a `for` construct.  There are many, many ways that this can go wrong.

This is a good place to use `find` instead.  Try this:

```
/bin/sh -c "find dir/checkpoint/features.txt -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname '20*' -exec echo \"hello\" \;"
```

Besides eliminating the error-prone use of `ls`, you avoid the sub-shell and all of the issues that it brings with it.

Follow-up in response to your comment:

I'm assuming that you're using `awk -F/ '{print $NF}'` to grab the name of the folder in which the file lives (that is, the last directory name before the filename).  The commands [`basename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) and [`dirname`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname) can be used to do this for you.  This should make your script a bit easier.  Place the following into a script file:

```
#!/bin/sh
folder=$(basename $(dirname $1))
mkdir -p #{nfs_checkpoint}/${folder}
cat #{result_location}/${folder}/20* > #{nfs_checkpoint}/${folder}/features.txt
```

And execute it like this:

```
/bin/sh -c "find dir/checkpoint/features.txt -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname '20*' -exec yourscript.sh {} \;"
```

Comment: It would be clearer to switch to single quotes on the outside instead of trying to escape the inner double quotes. `/bin/sh -c 'foo "bar"'` instead of `/bin/sh -c "foo \"bar\""`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Well just for the sake of simplicity I pasted the command like that in the question but the real one is `for dirname in $(ls -d #{result_location}/20*|awk -F/ '{print $NF}');do;mkdir -p #{nfs_checkpoint}/${dirname};cat #{result_location}/${dirname}/20* > #{nfs_checkpoint}/${dirname}/features.txt;done`. The thing i am struggling with mainly is how to get just the filename (not filepath) through find

Comment: `ls -b` might also work. At least for the GNU user land. However, I also prefer `find` and pipe that into a `while read` ...

Comment: @0xC0000022L- No, `for` still chokes on the output of `ls -b` if a file or folder name has spaces in it.  `find` is really the only way to do this safely.